# .intersects() from for loop is not working

Tags: java, for-loop

I have two arraylists here, that contain rockets and projectiles:

```
public static ArrayList<Projectile> projectiles = new ArrayList<Projectile>();
private static ArrayList<Rocket> rockets = new ArrayList<Rocket>();
```

Every now and then, a projectile and a rocket are added to the appropriate arraylist:

```
rockets.add(new NormalRocket(x, -10, 70, 0, 2); // the constructor is (int x, int y, int speed, int dir, int health) but only x and y are relevant.
```

Both Rocket and Projectile classes have the method:

```
public Rectangle bounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
}
```

And subclasses such as NormalRocket and MachineGunProjectile also have it:

```
public Rectangle bounds() {
    return super.bounds();
}
```

Now, I have a method that checks for collision between the rockets and projectiles like so:

```
private void collision(){
    for(int i = 0; i < rockets.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < projectiles.size(); j++){
            if(rockets.get(i).bounds().intersects(projectiles.get(j).bounds())){
                System.out.println("HIT!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when they do intersect, nothing appears to happen. Does someone know what is going on or does this require more code to debug?

Comment: The code you've given us is basically just calling an API function a few times, not much can go wrong there. We need more code.

Comment: I don't get something; rockets are projectiles.. Why do you have separate lists for them?

Comment: post your intersects implementation

Comment: "HIT" is never printed?

Comment: @JoshM I suppose but I just separated them into two different lists since they come from different sources.

Comment: @arynaq not it's not.

Comment: @Adi My assumption is that it's [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects(java.awt.Rectangle)).

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. It should be a matter of a very small and simple console app, doing nothing but showing what's wrong.

Comment: Post your intersects method

Comment: @Dukeling - Thanks. I didn't know its part of standard library.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you some hints to debug your problem

1. Try to drawtext the x,y positions of your rockets and projectiles.
2. Try to draw the bounding rectangle too, so that you can see if the bounding rectangles are really drawn correctly or not.
3. Check the intersection functions by drawing two rectangles that CAN intersect and check the output value.